# Помогите застрял в данной проблеме

Tags: javascript

нужно сделать переключатель(чекбокс)с надписью “транслитерировать”. При его активации в тексте сообщения(текст мы набираем в инпуте) все кириллические символы переводятся в аналогичные латинские, при деактивации - все латинские приводятся в аналогичные кириллические.

Comment: Так проблема в чём конкретно? Непонятно как функцию по клику на чекбокс запустить, или как кириллицу в латиницу перевести?

Comment: как кириллицу в латиницу перевести

Comment: Заведите 2 массива: один с кириллическими символами, второй - с символами, в которые нужно транслитерировать. При вводе данных в поле считывайте кириллический символ, заменяйте его необходимым из второго массива.

Comment: Дайте индексируемый заголовок вопросу

Answer (score 2):

Написать функцию, которая будет маппить одно на другое. Ну вот небольшой пример. Первое, что пришло в голову. Может, есть способ более оптимально это сделать. Но это по крайней мере работает. Остаётся только наполнить массивы.

```js
const RU = ['а', 'б', 'в', 'г'];
const EN = ['a', 'b', 'v', 'g'];

function translate(str) {
  return str.split('').map(el => {
    return EN[RU.indexOf(el)];
  }).join('');
}

console.log(translate('бага'));
console.log(translate('гага'));
console.log(translate('ага'));
console.log(translate('баба'));
```